# How to give In-Air Momentum to a CharacterController-Based Player in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to make a (relatively) basic movement control system using the CharacterController.

Everything seems to be working fine-ish so far - except for one thing, which is the behavior of the Player in mid-air.

What I want the player to do is keep the momentum he had when executing the jump and maybe have slight control over his velocity.

What I currently have is something that feels like surfing in CS:GO - movement works the same in mid-air as it does on the ground.

Now, I only started coding in unity and C# in general 2 days ago, so everything is still super rough to  me.

I'll put my entire script responsible for the player movement below - please excuse the spaghetti-code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    
    //Movement Multipliers
    private float speedMult = 1f;
    private float speed;
    public float baseSpeed = 20f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;

    public float walkMult = 1f;
    public float sprintMult = 1.5f;
    public float crouchMult = 0.5f;
    private int jumpAmount = 2;
  
    public float airSpeed = 6f;

    public float  crouchYMult = 0.5f;
    private float startYMult = 1f;

    public MovementState state;


    public enum MovementState
    {
        walking,
        sprinting,
        crouching,
        air
    }

    //Gravity Stuff
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.5f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;

    private void StateHandler() 
{

    if(isGrounded && Input.GetButton("Sprint"))
        {
            state = MovementState.sprinting;
            speedMult = sprintMult;
            
        }
        else if(isGrounded && Input.GetButton("Crouch"))
        {
            state = MovementState.crouching;
            speedMult = crouchMult;
            
        }
        else if(isGrounded)
        {
            state = MovementState.walking;
            speedMult = walkMult;
        }
        else
        {
            state = MovementState.air;
           
        }

}
    private void Start() 
    {
        startYMult = transform.localScale.y;    
    }

   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        StateHandler();


        if (isGrounded)
        {
            jumpAmount = 2;
        }

        //Gravity
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -5f;
        }

        //Movement
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        
        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        
        


        

       
       
        if (move.magnitude > 1)
        {
            move = move.normalized;
        }
        

        speed = speedMult * baseSpeed;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        //Jumping
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }
        else if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && jumpAmount > 0)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * 1.2f * -2f * gravity);
            jumpAmount -= 1;
        }



        if (isGrounded)
        {
            controller.stepOffset = 0.5f;
        }
        else 
        {
            controller.stepOffset = 1f;
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;


        controller.Move (velocity * Time.deltaTime);




        if(Input.GetButton("Crouch"))
        {
           transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, crouchYMult, transform.localScale.z);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, startYMult, transform.localScale.z);
        }

        

       

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a ridgidbody 3D to your player. If so all you need to do is calculate the vector3 and the velocity when not grounded. check this url for more clarification : [maybe this is what you look for](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1761630/solved-prevent-movement-while-in-the-air-while-kee.html)